# Issues implementing recursive function in R - fisher scoring

Tags: r, recursion

I am trying to implement Fisher Scoring on simulated i.i.d. Poisson data, but I am getting a stack overflow error. I did some simple prints from the function and found that the guess value is not changing after the first iteration.

```
fs_pois <- function(data, true, guess) {
if (abs(guess-true) < 0.01) return(guess)
else return(fs_pois(data, true, guess + (mean(data)*exp(-guess))-1))
}

data <- rpois(100,lambda=0.34)
fs_pois(data, 0.34, 0.36)
```

produces

```
Error: C stack usage  7970416 is too close to the limit
```

Does anyone know what is going on?
Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. After thinking about convergence, I looked back at the mathematical model and found that I had left out a log and in addition confused convergence to true parameter value with convergence to the ML estimate. My revised code is below:

```
fs_pois <- function(data, MLE, guess) {
  cat(guess,"\n")
  if (abs(guess-MLE) < 0.01) return(guess)
  else return(fs_pois(data, MLE, guess + (mean(data)*exp(-guess))-1))
}
set.seed(111)
data <- rpois(25,lambda=2)
fs_pois(data, log(mean(data)), -1)
```

As a general note to anyone reading: this is probably not how one would ever implement fisher scoring. This was simply for practicing recursion in R.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating `guess` with `(mean(data)*exp(-guess))-1`, what does not use `true` what you use in `abs(guess-true)` for the decision to exit. In your case the exit condition is not reached after 7970416 steps and typical the part `(mean(data)*exp(-guess))-1` is getting to `0`. Maybe you should use `(mean(data)*exp(-guess))-1` for the exit decision.

```
fs_pois <- function(data, guess) {
  d <- (mean(data)*exp(-guess))-1
  if (abs(d) < 0.01) return(guess)
  fs_pois(data, guess + d)
}

set.seed(7)
data <- rpois(100,lambda=0.34)
fs_pois(data, 0.36)
#[1] -0.9326207
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the goal of fisher scoring is to get as close to the true value as possible, which is why the "true" value was implemented into the function and the exit condition.

Comment: Yes, but they have to be related. Otherwise it might not find an end of the itteration - like in your example.